# Showing div based on element count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Was hoping someone could help me with an if statement in jquery based on how many elements of a certain class there are alreadd present in a page.

So I have a div with the class of 'view-more' and I want to only show it if there are more than 6 divs with the class of 'house-card'. I can use jquery to count how many divs there are (just shown in my example in a 'results' div to test the code so far), but after that I'm stuck.

```js
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "count:" + document.querySelectorAll('.house-card').length; 
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: None of that code snippet is jQuery... ?

Comment: I'm not sure what help you need. You already know how to get the `length` of an array of elements, you know what an `if` statement is. The only thing you're missing is an `<` operator and showing/hiding the element, the latter is trivial to Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
var showViewMore = document.querySelectorAll('.house-card').length > 6;
document.querySelector('.view-more').style.display = (showViewMore ? 'inherit' : 'none');
```

You just need to change the style of the element.  Or optionally you could toggle a class on it that applies the display status.